# Mavericks - Safari 7 - BROKEN Animated GIF

Tags: safari, macos

Animated GIF are things of the past (remember 90's web site) ... but some cool kids are still using it : 9gag

Well they are seriously broken when display in Safari 7 ... has anyone an idea.

Running Maveriks on my MBA 11".

Comment: In what way are animated GIFs broken? Would you provide a screenshot of the problem and/or a link to a site containing such a GIF so others can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I've noticed the same thing, most prominently because my bank requires me to hold up a reading device to the screen on which a GIF is flashing codes in order to generate a TAN (funky stuff). I'd guess it's a bug or undesired side effect of the new AppNap technology which gets fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Safari Version 7.0 (9537.71). GIFs will play through once, then only play for as long as the cursor is moving. Have been trying to find some setting in prefs or under the Develop menu for a way to allow GIFs to loop continuously.

Comment: It's happening to me too!